# ASP.NET MVC Cannot Implicitly Convert Type System.Collections.Generic.List<string> to 'string'

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to use EF to retrieve data from SQL and put it into a list of type viewmodel.
But when I try and retrieve the data it gives the following error: `Cannot Implicitly Convert Type System.Collections.Generic.List<.string> to 'string'`

I'm only trying to retrieve the ID and ProductName columns from the database.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult TableReport()
{
    List<ProductViewModel> products = new List<ProductViewModel>();
    ProductViewModel product = new ProductViewModel();
    product.Product = db.Products.Select(z => z.ProductName).ToList();
    product.ID = db.Products.Select(z => z.ProductID).ToList();
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Read your code out loud. *"Create an empty list of ProductViewModels. Create an empty ProductViewModel. Assign the list of all product names as the product name for that single empty ProductViewModel. Assign the list of all product ids as the id for that single empty ProductViewModel"*. No wonder it is not working, is it? Instead you should have done `var products = db.Products.Select(z => new ProductViewModel() { ID = z.ProductID,  Product = z.ProductName}).ToList();`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'm very very new to EF so any suggestions/tips are appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GSerg: Read your code out loud. "Create an empty list of ProductViewModels. Create an empty ProductViewModel. Assign the list of all product names as the product name for that single empty ProductViewModel. Assign the list of all product ids as the id for that single empty ProductViewModel". No wonder it is not working, is it? Instead you should have done var products = db.Products.Select(z => new ProductViewModel() { ID = z.ProductID,  Product = z.ProductName}).ToList();

Answer (score -1):

You are putting a list in a `string`

Change your Viewmodel to

```
 public class ProductViewModel
 {
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public List<string> Product { get; set; }
 }
```

And you are also trying to put a list in an `int`. That won't work either.

Comment: @Franco Did it really? How was your next line, `product.ID = db.Products.Select(z => z.ProductID).ToList();`?

Comment: @GSerg It solved my error but it was not a solution for what I was trying to do. Your code worked and solved my issue.